# XPages REST service and authentication with external systems

Tags: rest, authentication, xpages

I would love to know what methods are being used by XPages developers to allow non-Domino systems to authenticate with and consume REST Services. My REST services are built using the extension library's REST control.

Examples of work you have done would be awesome and much appreciated.

Regards,

Dan

Answer (score 6):

The common way is to use Basic Auth (it is statless). Another way is to implement your own stateless token solution. An example can be found here: https://github.com/hasselbach/domino-stateless-token-servlet

The stateless token has the advantage that the token can be stored in devices like smartphones without compromising the user's authentication data. And it is still valid even if a user changes it's password.